# Find a Lib parses User Agent String of Mobile Devices

Tags: java, user-agent

I want to write a java service that parses `User Agent String` of requests from `Mobile Devices`.

The information that I want extract is:

- Operation Name
- Operation Version
- Device Type
- Browser Name
- Browser Version

I searched some lib for Java:

- [UserAgentUtils](http://code.google.com/p/user-agent-utils/)
- [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/)-Wireless Universal Resource FiLe

In that I have used `UserAgentUtils` to parse user agent string from PC request.

But It not focus `Mobile Devices`.

I also tried `WURFL`, It's quit good.

Can you suggest me other Lib.

I want find a Lib that parse user agent string focus `Mobile Devices`.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

I'm working for some time on an user agent parser library (called [UADetector](http://uadetector.sourceforge.net)) based upon the database of [user-agent-string.info](http://user-agent-string.info). For now it is only possible to distinguish Mobile browsers rather than Mobile Devices. But we can extend this library to be able to scan different signatures.

To develop a more convenient access, we can build a Signature-Enum right into the class `UserAgent` as a set, like this:

`Set<Signature> getSignatures();`

and we can also add some Is-Methods:

`boolean isNexus();`

`boolean isIPhone();`

`boolean isIPad();`

etc.

But for this step, i need currently some input/support by you (and/or other developers) to collect mobile device signatures (in user agent strings).

Comment: Thanks @dubquery! I'm using WURFL http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/. It publics a database of infomartion of mobile devices and some API for query the database (Java, PHP,...). It contains very kind of devices.